# making custom ads for iphone application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i would like to display ads from my server in a uiwebview placed inside my application for which i will be sending some data from the phone to my server but what i have heard sending user data to your server in application will lead to the application being rejected?? is it true?? is there any other way to implement own custom ads from my server into the application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true, as long as your server aren't belong to some company in the mobile OS business.

Comment: and apple wont be having any problem regarding making money from clicks??

Comment: according to the agreement, no